# code signing error while integrating bot for simulator only

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode5, bots

I am integrating bot to run on iOS simulator only not any device but still getting code signing error- No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities(i.e. certificate and private key pairs) code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'

I have selected only one simulator under specific devices at the time of creating bot.

Why this is the problem for simulator too.

I have also tried by checking `don't code sign` option. But integration still failed with error-

> CodeSign error:code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS7'>

How to fix it?
Plz help...

Answer (score 0):

Why not to add development provisioning profile to that OS X Server? Just send the file to that machine and open it with Xcode.

To make sure everything goes OK I'm usually checking that I can run my app on that server just from Xcode.

`Don't code sign` option is not working now because, as you can see, code signing is required in the iOS7 SDK. Not sure if it's a bug or feature.